# Toggling doesnt work javascript , No errors

Tags: javascript, html

Ive tried making a normal display property change like this

```
b.onclick = function MyFunc(){
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
```

and it worked pretty good , But im trying to toggle it so that when the user clicks on the button it'll either hide itself or be shown , I tried this using a simple if/else but it's not working and i checked the console and there are no errors

This is the written html

```
<div id="header">
            <ul>
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <a href="#1">First</a>
                <a href="#2">Second</a>
                <a href="#3">Third</a>
                <a href="#4">Fourth</a>
                <a href="#4">Fifth</a>
                <a href="#4">Sixth</a>
                <a href="#4">Seventh</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button>Click</button>
```

And this is the JS for it

```
var x = document.getElementById("header"),
    b = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
if (x.style.display == "none"){
    b.onclick = function MyFunc(){
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
else{
    b.onclick = function MyFunc(){
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Since there're no erros im pretty sure the problem is in how i used the function but could anyone point to me how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `onClick` action each time and **THEN**, once it is called, check your style and act upon that data.

Try writing your JS code like this (HTML doesn't change):

```
    var x = document.getElementById("header"),
        b = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
         b.onclick = function MyFunc(){
                if (x.style.display == "none"){
                x.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
        }
```

As that, your condition will be checked after each action Call, whereas in your code logic the condition was checked only once on page load and defining the behavior of your `onClick` action for as many times as you will click it.

Comment: Oh thanks it works now perfectly well
Was the problem because i cannot use the same object ```b.onclick``` twice ?

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help :) Don't forget to write my answer as the correct one! It was just because your action was not called the second time.

Comment: I will , 10 minutes thing though xD 
Also could you tell me exactly how was the action not called ? Didn't i make the if statement for it to work as opposites ?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I've been a little fast :) Your code is loaded only once, so that means when the page is loaded, your if statement is checked. Thus in your code, It was not checked again when you click your button.

Comment: But shouldnt it have been checked if , for example the first click it's displayed to block , so that way it'll go through the statement to reverse it back to none and vice versa ?

Comment: I edited the post with a little sentence at the end, I hope it's clearer than my comment above ahah